# Blank value handling while creating a JSON file with nested objects from a csv file using Pandas to feed to Elasticsearch

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.9.5/Pandas 1.1.3

I use Pandas `read_csv` to read values from a csv file and create a JSON file of key-value pairs, which I then feed into an ElasticSearch index using bulk ingest helper of python elasticsearch.   Normally, a given JSON object that gets created from a row in the csv file looks like this:

```
{
  "id":1,
     "org":{
        "data":"ABC",
        "type":"XYZ"
           },
     "location":"123"
}
```

The problem is when a value in the csv file is blank, instead of it being written as a blank string, it's written like this (see the `data` value):

```
{
  "id":1,
     "org":{
        "data": null,
        "type":"XYZ"
           },
     "location":"123"
}
```

... then ElasticSearch throws an error when trying to ingest this as a document b/c of the `null`. In addition, these particular fields in Elasticsearch also do not allow empty strings.

How can I replace the `null` value in the resulting JSON object with a string, say, `"none"` or `"N/A"`?

So far everything I've read on S/O refers to the `na_values` parameter of the `read_csv` function, but according to the docs, that is meant to tell `read_csv` what additional values you want to be interpreted as NaN over and above the defaults.

Here is the code I'm using to read from the csv and create the json file:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import os

csv = "/Users/me/file.csv"
csv_file = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=",", header=0, index_col=False)
csv_file['org'] = csv_file[['data', 'type']].apply(lambda s: s.to_dict(), axis=1)
csv_file[['id', 'org', 'location']].to_json("file.json", orient="records", lines=True, date_format="iso", double_precision=10, force_ascii=True, date_unit="ms", default_handler=None)
```

Comment: Please add the code that shows how you're reading the csv file and writing it to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe probably has some `NaN` values that are being converted to `null` in json. So the easiest fix is to replace the `NaN` values with empty strings before converting to json:

```
csv_file = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=",", header=0, index_col=False)
csv_file.fillna("", inplace=True)
# ... contiue with the code here
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks.